# AngularFirebase2 , Ionic 3 : Return data through firebase is not working completely

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on a project about CRUD.

When i tried to display data from firebase with observable at first application(screenshots and codes are called by firstApplication ) everything is working stable. But when i try these code ( completely same without variable names) at second application i got

`Observable<{}> not assignable to type Observable<any[]>` error when i put my mouse into red line which is variable's under

**But when i count to ion-options which I used for display datas from firebase number of data is true. I just do not get it to data index**.

[Like That i put it "a"  s for count easier.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lislc.png)

**Second Application(Which is does not working) is below**

[Red Line under at this.cityNameRef$ variables.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EBxI.png)

**add-book.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase , AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { getNameOfCity } from '../../model/getNameOfCity.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-add-book',
  templateUrl: 'add-book.html',
})

export class AddBookPage {
    //cityName = {} as getNameOfCity;
    //cityNameRef$: AngularFireList<getNameOfCity>
    cityNameRef$: Observable<any>;

    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public navParams: NavParams,
        private database: AngularFireDatabase
        ) {

        this.cityNameRef$ = this.database.list('Cities/').valueChanges();

    }
}

<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>addBook</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
```

**add-book.html**

```
<ion-header>

      <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>addBook</ion-title>
      </ion-navbar>

    </ion-header>

    <ion-content padding>

        <ion-select >
            <ion-option *ngFor="let form of cityNameRef$ | async">
                {{ form.nameOfCity }} {{form.value}} 
            </ion-option>

        </ion-select>

    </ion-content>
```

**But when I come to first Application ( which is work stable )**

[Everything working stable and there is no error message but codes are same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD9x9.png)

**add-book-working-stable.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AddShoppingPage } from '../add-shopping/add-shopping'; 
import { AngularFireDatabase , AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database'; 
import { ShoppingItem } from '../../app/models/shopping-item/shopping-item.interface';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-shopping-list',
  templateUrl: 'shopping-list.html',
})

export class ShoppingListPage {
     shoppingListRef$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private database: AngularFireDatabase
    ) {

    this.shoppingListRef$ = this.database.list('Cities/').valueChanges();

  }

  navigateToAddShoppingPage(){
    this.navCtrl.push(AddShoppingPage);
  }

}
```

-

```
 "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
 "angularfire2": "^5.1.1",
 "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
 "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
```

Any idea about what is the problem or what is the I do not get it.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its basically saying your object not an array. When you make any to any array should be resolved.

from

```
 cityNameRef$:Observable<any>;
```

to

```
 cityNameRef$: Observable<any[]>;
```

Comment: This is helped me a lot. Thanks!